# Html.Grid: What is IGridColumn.Attributes()?

Tags: mvccontrib

I am new to MVC2 and I am using Html.Grid on my view.

I would like to know what Attributes() is in the following context and for what purpose and how it is used?

```
<%= Html.Grid<MyViewModel>(Model.MyPagedList)
        .Columns( column => {
             column.For(x => x.Amount).Attributes(...
```

I couldn't find much on Google.

Thanks.

Comment: I think Html.Grid or IGridColumn is a third party extended html helper or a custom html extended helper.  Never heard of it as a part of Asp.net MVC2.

Comment: Thanks Rob. I've changed the tag accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With [David](https://stackoverflow.com/users/424788/david)'s help figured out that this is used to set the html attributes. 
Ref: [Html.Grid right align data in column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3518679/html-grid-right-align-data-in-column)